# Security when using php cookies

Tags: php, security, cookies

I use cookies to check the user..but if someone kidnaps the cookie data, then he could pretend to be the user,.. same true with session too..

How can I make sure that when the user navigates and enters his pages, it is the actual user and not the one who hijacked the cookie/session?

(I cant make the user fill his user name and password every page, so that is not an option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the "secure" flag on your cookies (see [`session_set_cookie_params`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) or the ini settings), redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS, and only generate links to HTTPS (to prevent unnecessary redirects).

The "secure" flag tells the browser to never send the cookie over HTTP, e.g. if your user were to type in the HTTP url to your site. The SSL will take care of end-to-end encryption, protecting the cookie from eavesdropping. You could additionally do an IP check, but this would be inconvenient for some legitimate edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If someone has someone else's credentials then the battle is lost.

Run all your data over HTTPS so it is encrypted (so safe from being stolen in transit) and trust your users to secure their own end points (since you have no other choice).

Comment: See also: [Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) and the insecurity of open wifi.

Comment: so there will be pages when they have to login again... hmmm.. but why hacking doesnt happen in other sites like youtube? why cant someone get your cookie and enter and edit your channel..or maybe delete it

Comment: @Adam Backstrom — Hence running everything over HTTPS. Firesheep only works because Facebook drops back to unsecured HTTP once initial authentication is done.

Comment: @WithFlyingColors — Why will there be pages when they have to log in again? Hacking does happen in other sites, see Adam's link to Firesheep.

Comment: ssl is what my web host provides. I think I have that..but I mean programmatically

Comment: @Quentin The article says as much. It's just a practical application of the attack in question.

Comment: hmm.. I guess I should be precautious like amazon and ebay,  use timeouts and password filling before the user makes any changes.. such as buying things online

Answer (score 1):

Use a reasonable timeout (X minutes) and check for simultaneous activity from multiple IP addresses / browsers / OSes / etc. It isn't perfect, but may block most attackers.